# APScheduler max allowed running time for task instance?

Tags: apscheduler

Is there any maximum allowed running time for a task instance in APScheduler?
What is the default value and how do I change it?

I have been facing problems in running tasks that last for longer time.

Answer (score 1):

After asking about it at `#apscheduler` on freenode, I understood that there is no maximum allowed running time for a task. It doesn't make sense to have one, and even if it does, it should default to infinity.

However, there is a configurable parameter that allows controlling the maximum number of tasks that can run in parallel and that defaults to 1.